# Placing the contents of a linked list in an array reference

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, memory-management, linked-list

My instructions are...

```
// Description: Places the payload contents of the list in the
    //          array referenced by 'populateMeWithElements'.
    // Returns the number of elements that were placed
    //          in the provided memory location.
    // Precondition: Enough memory has been allocated to the provided
    //          memory location to hold the full contents
    //          of the list.
    // Postcondition: The memory allocated for 'populateMeWithElements'
    //          has been deallocated after the completion of
    //          this method call.
    int getListElements(int* populateMeWithElements);
```

I have this written...

```
int OOLList::getListElements(int* populateMeWithElements) {
    int count = 0;
    OOLNode* iterator = this->start;
    int* populateMeWithElements = new int[getListSize()];
    for (int i = 0; iterator->next != NULL; i++) {
        populateMeWithElements[i] = iterator->payload;
        iterator = iterator->next;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

but I am not sure if it is correct and if it is...

1. How do I display the contents in my driver
2. Where I deallocate the memory (do I do this in the driver or in the function that I wrote?)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

Comment: That postcondition makes no sense. *"You want me to put values into that array, then deallocate it, then tell you how many there were??"*

Comment: @Beta I believe that I'm supposed to use a pointer

Comment: Remove the line that creates a local `populateMeWithElements` variable that shadows the parameter and i think your code will work

Comment: @AlanBirtles actually, it won't work with just that change, because there are 2 other bugs in the code: 1) the `int* populateMeWithElements` parameter is being passed by value when it needs to be passed by reference in order for the function to return the `new`'ed pointer, and 2) in the loop, `iterator->next != NULL` needs to be `iterator != NULL` or else the loop will crash if the loop is empty, and skip the tail element if not empty

Comment: I don't think the parameter needs to be a reference, judging by the instructions in the comments it already contains an allocated array and the function should just be filling it

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declaring a local `populateMeWithElements` variable that *shadows* the input `populateMeWithElements` parameter.  You are filling the array that you allocate locally, you are not populating the caller's array at all.

For that matter, your function should not be using `new[]` at all, since the instructions clearly state that the precondition of the function is that the caller has already allocated an array of sufficient size beforehand, and will deallocate that array after the function exits.  So, your function's job is merely to fill the caller's array, nothing more.

And on that task, your loop is wrong.  `iterator->next != NULL` needs to be `iterator != NULL`, otherwise if the list is empty then the 1st access of `iterator->next` will fail, and if the list is not empty then the `payload` of the tail node will be skipped.

Try this instead:

```cpp
int OOLList::getListElements(int* populateMeWithElements) {
    int count = 0;
    OOLNode* iterator = this->start;
    for (int i = 0; iterator != NULL; i++) {
        populateMeWithElements[i] = iterator->payload;
        iterator = iterator->next;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

```cpp
OOLList list;
// populate list as needed...
int* elements = new int[list.getListSize()];
int count = list.getListElements(elements);
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // use elements[i] as needed...
}
delete[] elements;
```

The function can be simplified a bit further:

```cpp
int OOLList::getListElements(int* populateMeWithElements) {
    int count = 0;
    for (OOLNode* iterator = this->start; iterator != NULL; iterator = iterator->next) {
        populateMeWithElements[count++] = iterator->payload;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Or even:

```cpp
int OOLList::getListElements(int* populateMeWithElements) {
    int* ptr = populateMeWithElements;
    for (OOLNode* iterator = this->start; iterator != NULL; iterator = iterator->next) {
        *ptr++ = iterator->payload;
    }
    return ptr - populateMeWithElements;
}
```